# Does "Find my" offline mode work for you?

Tags: find-my-iphone, find-my

So yesterday I tried to test the "Find my" **offline mode** on two iPhones and one Mac. I turned one phone (A) into airplane mode, the second phone (B) is connected to the internet and marked it (A) as lost on my Mac. According to my understanding iCloud should push the lost_phone_key to all nearby iOS devices that send bluetooth beacons to find and lock the phone.

However I could not get this to work. Has somebody tried this? Did it work for you?

Comment: As there's confusion as to what Apple has actually implemented with 'Find My Network' and the BT beacon part of the your question, I'm going to delete my answer.  I think what you're referring to is ['Lost Mode'](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210515), that lets you mark your device as 'lost' and wipe it.